# How to center the window's position to the center of a large div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you have a window size of for example, 1280x720, and a large div that is 2000x2000(a pixel grid for example).

How would you center the window's view to the center of the pixel grid?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

use `flex` on the `div` wrapper.

```
          .box {
            display: flex;
          }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, however I am not looking to center divs. I am looking to center my window view, as in the (x,y) position of my view to the center of a div, if that makes any sense?